# Verify Token generated in C# with System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt

Tags: javascript, c#, reactjs, jwt

I have created a token like this in my web api with C#.

```
 private const string Secret = "someSecretKey";

        public static string GenerateToken(AuthModel user, int expireMinutes = 20)
        {
            var symmetricKey = Convert.FromBase64String(Secret);
            var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();

            var now = DateTime.UtcNow;
            var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
            {
                Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(new[]
                        {
                            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.Username),
                            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, ((Roles)user.RoleId).ToString()),
                            new Claim("guid",user.Guid)
                        }),

                Expires = now.AddMinutes(Convert.ToInt32(expireMinutes)),

                SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(new SymmetricSecurityKey(symmetricKey), SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature)
            };

            var stoken = tokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);
            var token = tokenHandler.WriteToken(stoken);

            return token;
        }
```

and when im usin that API for reactjs app i get the token but cant verify it with same secret key.
Im getting error INVALID SIGNATURE.
Im using jsonwebtoken npm package,

```
   import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken';
jwt.verify(token, keys.jwtSecret, async (err) => { 
      if (err) {
        //console.log('Token expired at: ', err.expiredAt)
        console.log("error", err)
      }
      else {
        dispatch(login(token));
      }
    });
```

i never hit that `dispatch(login(token))`.  I'm using this to check if token saved in `localStorage` is still valid to keep user signed in.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found solution. Couldn't just push `secretKey` in `jwt.verify(token,secretKey);` That doesn't work because some `base64 encoding/decoding` algorithms. What i had to do is first to make a Buffer from my secret like:

```
const secret = new Buffer("myTokeSecretString", "base64");
```

and then pass that `secret` to `verify` method and it works.